# How to load a app with new nib file when app is running on main window.xib

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, xib

I have got a sample app where I have delegate method and a main controller and mainwindow.xib.
when my application is loaded it directly loading on mainwindow.xib. But I want to do some changes like adding buttons and other UI things. But I don't have a nib file. So I added new nib file name called Newview.xib. So how do I load this nib file?

So my requirement is how to load this nib file on launch, what all changes I have to make in appdelegate method. Present code which is running is below

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  

    mainController = [[MainController alloc] init];

    [window addSubview:mainController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

goto `MainWindow.xib`, goto its *attribute inspector* -> view controller change the nib name to Newview. !!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use custom Newview.xib as window, You can  specify this in info.plist file of your project. Change "Main nib file base name" (NSMainNibFile) value to "Newview".